# How to say somebody is trouble (in a flirtatious way)?

Tags: traduction, anglais

I guess troublemaker, "perturbateur de troubles" is somewhat close. But wondering if there's a phrase or word that keeps the "naughtyness" kind of connotation. I'm trying to flirt with a girl I met in France but having trouble translating this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe *Un homme/une femme **à problèmes**.*

[e.g. from petitdiable's blog](http://www.petits-diables.com/article-eviter-les-filles-a-problemes-114995637.html):

> Eviter les "filles à problèmes".
>
> Est-ce que tu vois ce dont je parle? Les filles à problèmes...ce ne sont pas celles qui ont des problèmes, parce que là on est toutes dedans, ce sont celles qui en créent.

That might be too:

> Le genre de mec/nana **qui n'apporte que des emmerdes**.

*Perturbateur de troubles* doesn't work. *Perturbateur* already means troublemaker so that would mean Someone troubling the troubles...

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to a woman or girl that you find attractive but that you know might be trouble and say:

- Attention!  Qui s'y frotte, s'y pique!

That is:

- Careful!  Might get hurt!